# Three Color Bullet from library (character)

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to figure out if the colorful bullet option available in MS Word is a physical character and how to write it inline? All the other bullets seem to be variations of Wing Dings and are available alt key codes, but I see no supporting information relating to this ONE bullet...

[image]

Is there a supporting file that contains the library? Is it an image? A character key? What is it even called?

Comment: Make a Unicode plain text _test.txt_. Ensure that you edit in UTF-8 (like with Notepad++). Then try copy paste. With a bit of effort you can determine the Unicode code point (symbol number), and search for it.

Comment: I have tried that and nothing gets pasted. Telling me it is not an actual character. Bullets will show up in Notepad++ bit this just shows a blank space about a tabs length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a GIF file. You can retrieve it by creating one, saving the file, changing the ending to .zip and unzipping it. It gets stored in the word/media folder in the XML:
[image: Multicolor Bullet]

Comment: Wow, thank you! That is very handy information as well.